# Простейшее веб-приложение

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-сервер

Необходимо сделать простейшее веб-приложение, которое будет отвечать *json*'ами на различные **GET** и **POST** запросы.

---

**Вопрос**: какую библиотеку/фреймворк лучше использовать?

---

Интересуют именно библиотеки/фреймворки для создания *простейших* веб-приложений, т.к., как мне кажется, **Django** и **Flask** (других не знаю) слишком "навороченные" для такого.

Comment: Flask - микроядерный фреймворк, в базовой комплектации он умеет только принимать http-запросы и отвечать на них. Какая уж тут навороченность?

Comment: попробуйте bottle, самый элементарный, как мне кажется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что Flask замечательно подойдет под эти требования, минимальное количество строчек кода для создания хэндлеров GET/POST запросов + большое количество документации, ну и "plug and play", не требуется танцев с бубнами чтобы все это заработало. А так, есть еще aiohttp и tornado, но это уже не будет просто в плане реализации.